# Creating Resource type constructor with @Value threw BeanCreationException; nested NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a springboot project, where I am picking a .properties file from application.properties

> application.properties

```
sample.prop.file=com.example.handler/signature.properties
```

and have created a Component to pass this file as InputStream and initialise the Bean

> Handler.java

```
@Component
public class Handler extends DefaultHandler {

private Resource properties;

public Handler(@Value("${sample.prop.file}") Resource properties) throws IOException {
    this.properties = properties;
    this.props = new Properties();
    this.props.load(this.properties.getInputStream());
  }
}
```

In my service I create an instance of Handler.java and add it as BindingProvider

> Service.java

```
@Service
public class Service {

@Autowired
private Handler handler;

public void doSomething() {
    //some logic
    someMethod(handler);
}
```

After following some similar queries I am trying constructor injection and using @Autowired in my Service to make sure my @Component is initialised before it is called.
But still upon running the project I am getting an error below.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Handler' defined in file [/Users/abc/APP/testService/target/classes/com/example/handler/Handler.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.handler.Handler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
... 32 common frames omitted
```

Any inputs/comments are appriciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If input parameter `properties` is null, you'll get NPE in the line `this.props.load(this.properties.getInputStream());`

Comment: getting NPE at 
`public Handler(@Value("${sample.prop.file}") Resource properties) throws IOException`

Answer (score 0):

If the file in classpath. put `classpath:` as follows.

```
@Value("classpath:${sample.prop.file}")
```

Comment: File is in classpath. This path is in application.properties and using @Value I am fetching it directly

Answer (score 0):

You should know that Resource is annotation and you can't create an instance of it.

So you may change properties from Resource to String because @Value("${sample.prop.file}") returns String. Your class may become like so:

```
@Component
public class Handler extends DefaultHandler {

    private Properties props;

    public Handler(@Value("${sample.prop.file}") String properties) throws IOException 
    {
        this.props = new Properties();
        String p =  Paths.get(properties).toAbsolutePath().toString();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(p);
        this.props.load(in);
    }
}
```

But make sure that the new file is accessable, i.e. in some absolute path!